# Hide String placeholder when using initial String from xml

Tags: android, string, resources, placeholder

this question is regarding the String placeholder mechanic in Android. There are plenty of posts about "how can I use placeholders" etc, but my question is quiet different (or I'm just plain stupid) and I can't find an answer on the web.

**How can I hide the placeholder in a String resource when I'm referencing it via an xml file?**

The point is, if I have a String resource like

```
<string name=mystring>There comes the placeholder: %s</string>
```

and I use it in my whatever.xml file and set the text of a TextView to android:text="@string/mystring" then it actually really displays *"There comes the placeholder: %s"*. But you can imagine I want to avoid that the users see "%s" ;-)

So how do we do that?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%s` in your string is not just a placeholder, it is a *format specifier*. You can read all about them here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

The short answer to your question is that it is **not possible** to hide this format specifier from your users. However, that is because strings with format specifiers in them **should not** be used as simple arguments to `android:text` attributes.

The correct use of these string resources is to populate the text of your `TextView` at runtime (in Java) using `Resources.getString(int id, Object... formatArgs)` (or `Activity.getString(int id, Object... formatArgs)`), at which time you will pass in the real value to be substituted into your string.

Using the naming from your example, you might have something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytextview);
    myTextView.setText(getString(R.string.mystring, "real value"));
}
```

Note that you can use `tools:text="@string/mystring"` in your layout to see the string at design time (though this will still include any format specifiers). Real users will never see this text, though.

Comment: Ok, someone saying it's not possible meets my needs :D I guess I'm just using "" for the real value param because I initially need the value to be empty.. that was the cause of this question...